# What does "cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const hand' to 'hand &' mean? (C++)

Tags: c++, reference, this

The error occurs when I try to do this

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const hand& obj)
{
    return obj.show(os, obj);
}
```

where hand is a class I've created, and show is

```
std::ostream& hand::show(std::ostream& os, const hand& obj)
{
    return os<<obj.display[0]<<obj.display[1]<<obj.display[2]<<obj.display[3]<<obj.display[4];
}
```

where display is declared as `char display[6]`.

Does anyone know what the error means?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to make `hand::show(...)` a `const` method; and it doesn't make sense to pass it obj reference -- it already receives that as the '`this`' pointer.

This should work:

```
class hand {
public:
  std::ostream& show(std::ostream &os) const;
...
};

friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const hand& obj)
{
    return obj.show(os);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the function itself to also be const (notice the "const" at the end of the first line):

```
std::ostream& hand::show(std::ostream& os, const hand& obj) const
{
    return os<<obj.display[0]<<obj.display[1]<<obj.display[2]<<obj.display[3]<<obj.display[4];
}
```